# Using advanced NDI to transmit video with HEVC compression bit rate

Tags: ios, c, hevc, h.265, ndi

I would like to know that after running this project, it can only be transferred correctly on mac, and a black screen will be displayed on windows, but ndi
Can the source name be found correctly? How to solve this problem? What are the main causes? Are there any specific solutions to recommend?

At first I thought it was an adaptation problem with resolution, etc., then
I tried changing these values, but it still didn’t work. I thought it might be a problem with the XCode environment, but using the normal version of NDI can display it correctly on Windows.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.